# matching using grep with single white space

Tags: regex, grep

I'm trying to match string using grep. I want all string that have two words one word can be anything and the other time. For example:

Input:

```
AZ time
CA summer time
Winter time
time here!
time in AZ
```

Output:

```
AZ time
Winter time
```

I tried using `grep "[a-zA-z] time$]"` but for some reason the output is:

```
AZ time
CA summer time
Winter time
```

Do you know why this is happening? There can only be one whitespace in the sentence. Basically the structure " time" Thanks!

Comment: Easy with the <br/>'s, you dont need 'em

Comment: The `[a-zA-Z]` is capturing the letter immediately before the word `time`, so you are capturing the `Z` in `AZ time`, `r` in `CA summer time`, and `r` in `Winter time`.  You want to use `^[a-zA-Z]+ time$` to match the front and end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `egrep`:

```
egrep "^[a-zA-Z]+ time$" file
AZ time
Winter time
```

Or using `grep` you can use:

```
grep "^[[:alpha:]]\+ time$" file
```

Comment: Your `[a-zA-z]` should have a capital `z`: `[a-zA-Z]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following.

```
grep '^[a-zA-Z]\+ time' file
```

Comment: why do you need the + ? I only want to mach it one itime

Comment: The `+` means any character of `a` to `z` (`1` or more times), if you take away the quantifier, it will only match a single letter of `a` to `z`